# What's the proper way to test for an unexpired cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm having trouble getting my code to ignore loading an expired cookie.

When I log a user in who wants to be remembered, I set a cookie like so...

```
setcookie('mysiteCookieBlah', $token, $expiry, '/', 'https://www.mysite.com', 1, 1);
```

Whenever they refresh the page, if they're not logged in ie don't have a user ID in session, I then check for the existence of the cookie to see if I should init auto-logging them in...

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mysiteCookieBlah'])) 
  $intiAutoLogin=true; 
else 
  $intiAutoLogin=false;
```

When they log out, I expire it...

```
unset($_COOKIE['mysiteCookieBlah']);
setcookie('mysiteCookieBlah', "", time()-3600, '/', 'https://www.mysite.com', 1, 1);
```

Next time the page refreshes,

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mysiteCookieBlah'])) 
  $intiAutoLogin = ?
```

should = false, right? At the moment, it sees the cookie every time, regardless if it's expired.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: `if(isset($_COOKIE['mysiteCookieBlah']) && !empty($_COOKIE['mysiteCookieBlah'])) {....` ?

Comment: To make sure that cookie would be expired you could store expired time on server side.

Comment: Thanks guys. After adding && !empty($_COOKIE['mysiteCookieBlah']) it's still triggering $intiAutoLogin=true.  I store and check the expiry in the database, but I don't want to hit the database up if the cookie itself is expired. I've tested some more and it seems the cookie isn't overwriting. I tried setting a brand new cookie too, and that isn't writing either, so I'll investigate some more. It's an AJAX request too fyi. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my logout cookie code to

```
setcookie("mysiteCookieBlah", "", time()-3600, '/');
```

and it worked. I have no idea why.